# How to retrieve the url from a browser in react native?

Tags: react-native, instagram-api

I'm quite new to react native and I want to create an Instagram authentication for my app for which I need it's access token. As stated in the docs, I have to visit this link https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token and when the user has authorised and authenticated the app, I'll be redirected to this link http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN from where I can grab my access token. But I'm not able to implement this as I'm unaware of the procedure on how to retrieve the token from the url in react-native once I'm redirected to this http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN.

I'm using WebBrowser (Expo) to open the links in the app.

PS: I'm using CRNA cli for my react-native-app

Answer (score 0):

From the example it states:

```
    import InstagramLogin from 'react-native-instagram-login'
<View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.refs.instagramLogin.show()}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Login</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <InstagramLogin
        ref='instagramLogin'
        clientId='xxxxxxxxxx'
        scopes={['public_content', 'follower_list']}
        onLoginSuccess={(token) => this.setState({ token })}
        onLoginFailure={(data) => console.log(data)}
    />
</View>
```

This suggests the token will be within your App state (either onLoginSuccess/Failure) is called. Access the token from there.

Comment: actually i'm using expo cli so i won't be able to use the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve Access token by using 'https://localhost' as re-direct url,

use your link in `webView`

eg:

```
   <WebView
                source={{
                  uri: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=https://localhost&response_type=token"
                }}
                onNavigationStateChange={state =>
                  this._onChangeNav(state)
                }
   />
```

And add method,

```
_onLoadAddNewCardView(state) {

   console.warn("RES=" + state.url);// Your url with ACCESS TOKEN

   let responseString = state.url;
   responseString = responseString.replace("https://localhost/?", "");

   // Here you will get the ACCESS TOKEN
}
```